# skill name in games

Tags: names

if you play games, you can see skill names or items like, Blade of the Ruined King or something like that.
is it ok if I use lowercase instead of capital letter?
doesn't it seem awkward to native english speaker? - like, blade of the ruined king.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, you should always capitalize a proper noun in English. Since your game items are presumably unique, their names should also be capitalized. [Here](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-proper.htm) is a reference for identifying proper nouns.
**If you plan to make a published work**, like a review of this game, **you should capitalize the item names**.

That being said, online games tend to have a very casual atmosphere, and it's very rare for the players to care about each other's grammar at all during play. In fact, even abbreviations, like (all-lowercase) "bork" for "Blade of the Ruined King" are thrown around all the time. So don't worry about it in-game. Source: I also play League.